# Remove parentheses without regex

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to turn something like this

```
NSString *stringWithParentheses = @"This string uses (something special)";
```

Into this, programmatically.

```
NSString *normalString = @"This string uses";
```

The issue is I don't want to use all these weird libraries, regex, etc.

Comment: Don't use regex. When you do, you will have two problems.

Comment: What's so weird about regex?

Comment: @Sebastian there's nothing 'weird' about it. It just gets confusing, unwieldy, and hard to embed in source code, hard to read, slower than traditional searching methods, and just doesn't make sense in this scenario.

Comment: @Sebastian this would be my only use for regex. Using built in methods would be much better than taking the time to implement regex

Comment: What do you wish to happen with nested pairs of parens? Should it try to match the outermost pairs and take care of them? Or just the first matches?

Comment: Just for the record, a regex solution is only one line and doesn't need any external library: `[stringWithParentheses stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\([^)]*\\)" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringWithParentheses length])]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just find the first open parentheses, note its index, find the closing one, note its index, and remove the characters between the indexes (including the indexes themselves).

To find the character use:

```
[string rangeOfString:@"("];
```

To remove a range:

```
[string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:...  withString:@""];
```

**Here is a solution:**

```
NSString* str = @"This string uses (something special)";
NSRange rgMin = [str rangeOfString:@"("];
NSRange rgMax = [str rangeOfString:@")"];

NSRange replaceRange = NSMakeRange(rgMin.location, rgMax.location-rgMin.location+1);

NSString* newString = str;

if (rgMin.location < rgMax.location)
{
    newString = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replaceRange withString:@""];
}
```

It won't work on nested parentheses. Or multiple parentheses. But it works on your example. This is to be refined to your exact situation.

Comment: "Just find" is left as an exercise to the user, huh? Not helpful in the slightest.

Comment: Even in it's updated form it doesn't answer the question. You start him on the right track, but never follow through with a complete solution.

Comment: I disagree with the downvote. The answer is useful. It is language independant and answer the question: how to proceed without regex.

Comment: being language independent is part of the problem. I am the down-voter, and I will not revoke it unless a full and complete solution to the OP's problem is given. This is not a site for language-agnostic answers in most scenarios, and this is one of them.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Well, I did provide a complete solution.

Comment: Your answer is correct for the example string in the question, but it throws an exception if there is a closing bracket before the first opening bracket.

Answer (score 5):

If you change your mind about the regex, here's a short, clean solution:

```
NSString *foo = @"First part (remove) (me (and ((me)))))) (and me) too))";
NSRegularExpression *expr = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\(.*\\)" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *bar = [expr stringByReplacingMatchesInString:foo options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, foo.length) withTemplate:@""];
```

Everything between `(` and `)` gets removed, including any nested parentheses and unmatched parentheses within parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

A way would be to find the position of the first occurrence of the '(' character and the last occurrence of the ')' character, and to build a substring by eliminating all the characters between these ranges. I've made an example:

```
NSString* str= @"This string uses (something special)";
NSRange r1=[str rangeOfString: @"("];
NSRange r2= [str rangeOfString: @")" options: NSBackwardsSearch];
NSLog(@"%@",[str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange(r1.location, r2.location+r2.length-r1.location) withString: @""]);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this in this situation. As it only trims from the end of strings, it won't do what the OP wants.

Comment: That will only remove the characters in the set.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: While the answer is correct, it'd be awesome for you to provide a solution that handled nested pairs of parentheses at the same time.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII You're right, I modified the code in a way that removes the characters between the first occurrence of '(' and the last occurrence of ')'.